# Thymeleaf template Image src attribute is malformated. need to be RFC 7230 and RFC 3986 compliant

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, thymeleaf

I have the following code in my Thymeleaf template:

```
<form action="#" th:object="${userDto}" method="post">
...
<img alt="" src="@{/ProfileImageServlet?imageId=*{profileImageId}}"
                             width="100" style="border-radius: 50%;" >
```

where ProfileImageServlet is supposed to generate the image dynamically using the Image Id in parameter *{profileImageId} (property in userDto). However, that is not happening. The application fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/@%7B/ProfileImageServlet?imageId=*{profileImageId}} ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `th:src` instead of `src`:

```
<img alt="" th:src="@{/ProfileImageServlet?imageId=*{profileImageId}}"
                             width="100" style="border-radius: 50%;" >
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. However, the system is still generated the error: "Invalid character found in the request target [/@%7B/ProfileImageServlet?imageId=*{profileImageId})} ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986"

Comment: That is very strange, looks like the Thymeleaf processing is not happening. Can you create a sample application that shows the problem on github?

Comment: I have just added a demo application in GitHub:https://github.com/satinder-2000/profileImageExample. Any issues please let me know.

Comment: Alternatively use the following GitHub link that will also demonstrates the same error : https://github.com/satinder-2000/profileImageDemo

Comment: @Singam I had a look to `profileImageDemo`, but I still see `src` instead of `th:src` in `UserRegisterConfirm.html`. Please change it and try again.

Comment: sorro for the late reply. I did try the above and ran the code as```th:src``` but in vain. No more error is being generated but no image gets displayed either.

Comment: just committed the code at  github.com/satinder-2000/profileImageDemo

Comment: That was rather strange. Anyway, I have made an update to ```profileImageDemo``` and the looks correct in GitHub.